# Can someone please explain why this statement gives the output as 'A', print (('A','B')[a == False]) . Initial value of a = True

Tags: python

Can someone please explain why the output is **A** for following code.

```
a = True
print (('A','B')[a == False])
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to analyse this yourself?

Comment: is that `a = True` or `==`?

Comment: @Tibebes.M, Sorry it was a = True. Corrected that now.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, This does answer my question, Thanks. 
But one more doubt, If we are using a True/False condition for indexing, like what is used here. So, it will never return an element with Index 2 or above, right? For ex. 
 print (('A','B','C','D')[a == False]) - I can never get 'C' or 'D' with this True/False Condition ?

Comment: No. If you read the linked answer, `False` has the value of 0 and `True` the value 1. So obviously no, you can't index 2 or 3, unless you do `1 + a == False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming first line is `a = True`, `a == False` evaluates to `false`, therefore boolean value of `0`. Therefore your expression is same as `print(('A', 'B')[0])` which prints 'A'